# Cannot convert type System.Windows.WindowCollection' to 'UITestApp.UiSimulator

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a wpf window with a few buttons, i do have another class where manipulation of wpf window is done. I need to disable a button of WPF window from the class after saving a file. This leads to the error

Error: Cannot convert type System.Windows.WindowCollection' to 'UITestApp.UiSimulator

forthe following code

```
if (result == true)
            {
                // Save document
                SaveParamFile(dlg.FileName);
                UISimulator uv = (UISimulator)Application.Current.Windows;
                uv.btnSave.IsEnabled = false;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are casting a WindowCollection to Window, that is why error throwing, you have to find the window from the collection and need to cast it.
if UISimulator is the main Window, you can use like this,

```
if (result == true)
            {
                // Save document
                SaveParamFile(dlg.FileName);
                UISimulator uv = (UISimulator)Application.Current.MainWindow;
                uv.btnSave.IsEnabled = false;
            }
```

or you have to find the window like below,

```
if (result == true)
        {
            // Save document
            SaveParamFile(dlg.FileName);
            UISimulator uv = (UISimulator)Application.Current.Windows.OfType<UISimulator>().FirstOrDefault();
            uv.btnSave.IsEnabled = false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Application.Current.Windows only contains windows that exist on the main UI thread. It's not good practice to create windows on any other thread but the main UI thread.

Comment: Then how can i access/manipulate features of a control om main UI. I am a beginner in wpf

Answer (score 0):

There's no way you can directly access/manipulate the UI from another thread. The only solution is to raise an event in the thread and then catch it in the UI thread. UI elements have very strict thread affinity requirements. This means you can only access the element from the thread hosting it. This includes all kinds of accesses including simple reads. You can implement this using delegate.
Put the following line where you need to update UI.
Use `[Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority, Delegate)]` to change the UI from another thread or from background.

```
 Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new ThreadStart(delegate
{
    //Update UI here
}));
```